# MapInfo tab file in Google Map

Tags: google-maps, mapinfo

In my asp.net 3.5 application, I'm using Google Map API v3. I want to draw layers using MapInfo Tab File and showing them on a Google Map.

Anyone have any idea about how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You may convert your *.tab* files to *kml* format (using the excellent [ogr2ogr](http://www.bostongis.com/PrinterFriendly.aspx?content_name=ogr_cheatsheet) tool for example or do it [natively](http://testdrive.mapinfo.com/techsupp/miprod.nsf/59d125f456480edb852562b5004f2c33/50bd7ab767b15f778525781e0049c043?OpenDocument) from MI itself) and then display them into Gmap. 
See this [sample page](http://code.google.com/intl/fr/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-kml.html) to explore the code.

Comment: Apart from this is there any other way to use TAB file in Google Map API v3.because I download the tool convert tab file into KML file but when I use it on Map it covers the whole map.                                    Thanks

Comment: have you tried ogr2ogr ?

Comment: yes I tried ogr2ogr tool but the returned KML file is not working for me.

Comment: What dos that mean? you should be more precise if you want any help. You can directly load your kml file from googlemap itself to test it, [like so](http://maps.google.com/maps?q=http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example1.kml).

Comment: What is your projection? Have you defined your projection? Open the resulting kml file with a text editor. What do you see?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 modes for converting to a KML file in mapinfo - 1 creates a raster, the other creates vectors.  It sounds like you may have used the raster option.